# Vietnamese accent

Tags: php, regex

I have this function and it can to remove accent but it do not work with vietnamese accent. I suppose it can be the same with other asian language.

How to improve this function to take in consideration accident language and asian.

example : 
Nông sản Khánh Hòa
Sản phẩm từ nuôi ong

Thank you

```
    protected function getSkipAccents(string $str, string $charset = 'utf-8'): string
{
  $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, $charset);

  $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z])(?:acute|cedil|caron|circ|grave|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);#', '\1', $str);
  $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z]{2})(?:lig);#', '\1', $str);
  $str = preg_replace('#&[^;]+;#', '', $str);
  $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $str); // Removes special chars

  return $str;
}
```

Comment: Most probably this problem is caused by the encoding.

Comment: You should post some example input and what you expect the output to look like. I suspect most people don't know what "Vietnamese accents" look like.

Comment: @Sammitch : see above : I insert one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intl's [Transliterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) will let you define far more in-depth transliteration rules. The full documentation on transliteration rules can be found on [icu-project.org](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

```
$input = " Nông sản Khánh Hòa Sản phẩm từ nuôi ong";

$tl = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII;');

var_dump(
    $input,
    $tl->transliterate($input)
);
```

Output:

```
string(52) " Nông sản Khánh Hòa Sản phẩm từ nuôi ong"
string(40) " Nong san Khanh Hoa San pham tu nuoi ong"
```

Answer (score -3):

Add missed chars yourself.

```
$word = getSkipAccents("bãy");
echo $word;

function getSkipAccents($str) 
{
    $str = preg_replace('/(à|á|ã|â|a)/', 'a', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(è|é|ê)/', 'e', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ì|í|i)/', 'i', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ò|ó|õ|ô|o)/', 'o', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ù|ú|u|u)/', 'u', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ý)/', 'y', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(d)/', 'd', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(À|Á|Ã|Â|A)/', 'A', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(È|É|Ê)/', 'E', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ì|Í|I)/', 'I', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ò|Ó|Õ|Ô|O)/', 'O', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ù|Ú|U|U)/', 'U', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ý)/', 'Y', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ð)/', 'D', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I feel sorry for whoever typed all that out instead of looking up the [`Transliterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) class.